# What is your experience using a Sound Device MixPre 3 II as Audio Interface on a WIndows 10 PC?

Tags: homerecording, computer

I need to buy a new USB audio interface for my laptop. And at the same, I've always dreamed to replace my good old [Marrantz PMD 670](https://mediawiki.middlebury.edu/LIS/Marantz_PMD670) fieldrecorder by something ligther, working at 96kHz, ...

I'm considering doing both at once and buying a Sound Device Mix Pre 3, that I'd use on the field to for my fieldrecording stuff and as an audio interface for my PC.

I read this was possible to use the MixPre as USB audio interface.
Can you share your experience on using a MixPre3 II as USB audio interface on a Windows10 system ?

My primary usages, on PC, are soundesign work, to record instruments, listen regular music, ...

Are there any issues ? How is the latency ? ...

Thanks

Comment: Latency is usually the computer's problem. The rest of your question I'm afraid is entirely opinion-based. We don't do product recommendations or reviews, sorry.

Comment: "opinion-based" ? not really more "experience-based" .

Comment: Answers can only be of the form "I like it, it works" or "I don't like it, it's buggy." Opinions. Please take the time to read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Well I disagree with your opinion on my question, but I guess I have little choice.

Comment: Two other users & an admin agreed with me. Sorry, but we just don't do "reviews" on stack exchange, You need a forum structure for that. SE is not a forum, it is a question & answer site. Please actually take the time to read the help pages I posted earlier.